# Import Excel Named Range into SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have an excel file 'test.xlsx' which contains a sheet called 'SheetName', which contains a named range called 'NamedRange'.

I want to write a script in visual basic to import these named ranges into an SQL database. So far I have tried openrowset, but I cannot find the correct syntax to reference a named range. An example of a query that doesn't work:

```
USE [Test_DataBase]
GO
SELECT * INTO New
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Test.xlsx', NamedRange);
GO
```

The error from this is: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "NamedRange". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I can however import the complete worksheet by using:

```
USE [Test_DataBase]
GO
SELECT * INTO New
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Test.xlsx', SheetName$);
GO
```

I have also tried:

```
USE [Test_DataBase]
GO
SELECT * INTO New
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Test.xlsx', SheetName$NamedRange);
GO
```

But that produces the following error: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "SheetName$NamedRange". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

So, can openrowset actually be used to reference named ranges? If not is there an alternative method I could use instead?

*This is my first question, I hope I've been clear enough and haven't broken any rules!

Craig

Comment: What makes the difference in Excel between "the data is dumped in a sheet" and "properly formatted as a table"? Can you provide some samples?

Comment: I *believe* the OP is saying that they want to right SQL like `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$TableName]` as opposed to `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B2:AD]`. Why they can't use the latter, I'm not sure.

Comment: Got it. In other words they want that to be as a permanent solution. If so, I'm against that solution

Comment: I have updated the question after finding the correct terminology, hope it makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use SSIS.
2. You can use Wizard "import data": Right click DB -> **Tasks** -> **Import Data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First install the driver, from the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO


USE YourDatabase;
GO
SELECT * INTO Table1
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\your_path\test.xlsx', [Sheet1$nr]);
GO
-- 'nr' is your named range
```

See these links for more details.

http://www.ashishblog.com/importexport-excel-xlsx-or-xls-file-into-sql-server/

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-using-tsql-to-import-excel-data-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#sixth

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
dbWb = ThisWorkbook.FullName
dsh = "SheetName$"

xlrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "].[" & dsh & "A1:X" & xlrow & "] as aa"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).